# Define BroadcastReceiver.onReceive with a method reference

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8, android-7.0-nougat

Using Jack support for Java 8, I'd like to be able to write something like that:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (!intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BINGO)) return;
    Log.d(TAG, "Bingo!");
}

... 

registerReceiver(this::onReceive, INTENT_FILTER_BINGO);
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Although `onReceive()` is the unique abstract method of `BroadcastReceiver`, that thing is not an **interface**, it's an **abstract class**, which don't appear to be replaceable by lambda expressions. Any suggestion to work around this?

Comment: You can create constructor for the class which extends BroadcastReceiver and pass Interface listener to that constructor. In onReceive method give call to the listener

Comment: I almost came to the same conclusion, except I'm not using a listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the trick outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424686/3168630), here is that I get:

```
public class BroadcastReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

    private final BiConsumer<Context, Intent> receiver;

    public BroadcastReceiver(final BiConsumer<Context, Intent> onReceive) {
        receiver = onReceive;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (receiver == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
        receiver.accept(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Not as concise as what I expected, but better:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(this::onReceive);
registerReceiver(receiver, INTENT_FILTER_BINGO);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend on the answer above, without BiConsumer (not available in APIs<24)

```
class BroadcastReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    public interface IBR {
        void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent);
    }

    private final IBR receiver;

    public BroadcastReceiver( IBR receiver ){
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        receiver.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

then, same as above or below

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(this::onReceive);
registerReceiver(receiver, INTENT_FILTER_BINGO);
```