# How to use class instead of interface for lambda param

Tags: java, java-10

Right now I have this:

```
  public static interface AsyncCallback<T, E> {
    public void done(E e, T v);
  }
```

I want to convert it to this so I use a boolean property on it:

```
  public abstract static class AsyncCallback<T, E> {
    boolean shortcircuit = false;
    public abstract void done(E e, T v);
  }
```

but now I am getting errors:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast '' to 'E'

and

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List conforms to
>   AsyncTask

the code I have that generates the errors is based off passing lambdas. Does anyone know why converting the interface to a class causes problems? Even if I comment out the `shortcircuit` field and just have the done method definition, same errors arise.

Comment: Looks like I am on Java version 10, not 11

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874325/java-8-lambda-expression-with-an-abstract-class-having-only-one-method

Comment: See [Abstract class as functional interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610207/), [Lambda Expressions for Abstract Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424410), [Java 8 lambda expression with an abstract class having only one method (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874325/) and [Why do I need a functional Interface to work with lambdas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010594).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use class instead of Interface ( Precisely to say **Fuctional Interface**).

See the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010594/why-do-i-need-a-functional-interface-to-work-with-lambdas) to know why do we need  functional Interface to work with lambda in java.

> In your case you are trying to use a class , which will obviously have
>   name, isn't. but to use lambda we have to use anonymous functions
>   which don't have name and type.

Comment: @AlexanderMills , your class will always have a name and type..so you cannot use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874325/java-8-lambda-expression-with-an-abstract-class-having-only-one-method @AlexanderMills check this link.

Comment: More importantly, the objects created for lambda expressions have an unspecified identity, so having a mutable boolean field whose behavior would depend on the object identity is precisely what the Java language wants to prevent.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by keeping the interface but also using a class:

```
  public static interface AsyncTask<T, E> {
    public void run(AsyncCallback<T, E> cb);
  }

  public static interface IAsyncCallback<T, E> {
    public void done(E e, T v);
  }

  public static abstract class AsyncCallback<T, E> implements IAsyncCallback<T, E> {
    public boolean shortcircuit = false;
  }
```

in circumstances where I must use an interface, I use the IAsyncCallback interface, where I can use a class, I use AsyncCallback class.