# Java method can't be applied with Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, overriding, functional-interface

I've watched and read https://caveofprogramming.com/java/whats-new-in-java-8-lambda-expressions.html and I follow the same pattern I did for runner object which works fine.

```
Runner runner = new Runner();
runner.run(() -> System.out.println("Print from Lambda expression"));
```

Then, I try to create a simple interface and class to apply what I learned. I just want to replace the anonymous class with a lambda expression. My understanding is a lambda expression is a shorter code for the anonymous class and improve readability.

So, I tried to initiate another instance called `eucalyptus1` and try to `@Override` the `grow()` method, but my IDE error message said:

> `grow()` in `com.smith.Eucalyptus` cannot be applied to `(lambda expression)`

**Could anyone point me out what I misunderstand here?**

The code is below:

```
// a simple interface
interface Plant {
    public void grow();
}

// apply interface to class
class Eucalyptus implements Plant {
    @Override
    public void grow() {
        System.out.println("This is from Eucalyptus");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an instance of Eucalyptus
        Eucalyptus eucalyptus = new Eucalyptus();
        eucalyptus.grow();

        // Anonymous class Myrtle from Plant interface
        Plant myrtle = new Plant() {
            @Override
            public void grow() {
                System.out.println("This was running from anonymous class from Plant Interface");
            }
        };

        myrtle.grow();

        // Try to create a lambda expression from Plant interface
        // and override grow() method
        // by print ("This was running from Lambda expression")

        // this won't work. why?
        Eucalyptus eucalyptus1 = new Eucalyptus();
        eucalyptus1.grow(() -> System.out.println("This from Lambda expression"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference there is that you're trying to override the implementation of `Eucalyptus` which is a class that implement the interface.

```
Eucalyptus eucalyptus1 = new Eucalyptus();
eucalyptus1.grow(() -> System.out.println("This from Lambda expression")); 
^__  // you cannot override a method using an instance of a class which is just an implementation of the interface
```

All you end up doing there is pass a lambda parameter and of course, a method without arguments in its definition wouldn't compile if supplied with one at the time of method call.

---

Instead, you can compare the way of implementing the lambda as :

```
//Anonymous class Myrtle from Plant interface
Plant myrtle = new Plant() {
          @Override
          public void grow() {
               System.out.println("This was running from anonymous class from Plant Interface");
          }
};
myrtle.grow();
```

can be represented as a lambda representation:

```
Plant lambdaRep =  () -> System.out.println("This is running via lambda from Plant Interface");
lambdaRep.grow();
```

Answer (score 10):

**Problem**

The method `grow` doesn't take any parameters, so you got the compilation error.

**Explanation**

The lambda `() -> System.out.println("This from Lambda expression")` itself can represent a `Plant` (not `Eucalyptus`*) instance:

```
Plant plant = () -> System.out.println("This from Lambda expression");
```

> Try to create a lambda expression from `Plant` interface and **override `grow()` method** by print `"This was running from Lambda expression"`.

There is a slight misunderstanding here. A lambda isn't supposed *to override a method*, it's up to *provide a method* based on a [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) type.

---

*If you were to define an `Eucalyptus` object by a lambda, it would be ambiguous and unclear what method the lambda would represent. Therefore, it's prohibited [(even for abstract classes with a single abstract method.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424577/4922375)

Answer (score 7):

Your use of lambda expression is incorrect here.

You use lambda expressions to implement an interface. In this case, you would be providing an implementation of `Plant` using a lambda expression, rather than calling that interface's method with a lambda expression:

Here's a normal use:

```
Plant eucalyptus1 = () -> System.out.println("This from Lambda expression");
eucalyptus1.grow(); // Prints "This from Lambda expression"
```

In other words, because you're having a functional interface, you should be able to avoid creating classes implementing it (anonymous or not).

So you should not need to create the `Eucalyptus` class at all.